# How to get a object with a special id out of the stack?

Tags: java, stack, loops, identifier

In my  cardgame-project, I simulate a cardpile with a stack. Each card of the pile/stack has an unique identifier.

Now I want to take the object with the specific identifier out of the stack.
Is there an efficient option to realize it? First I thought about an iterator which will iterate over the stack... but it's not an optimum solution if I have many cards on the stack.

Comment: Is a stack really the right choice here or are you required to use one?

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion here... the cards in the game is referred to as a "stack of cards", but should not represented by a stack data structure.  It's almost like a "banking queue" that can be represented by a linked list, to make iteration possible (to measure the annoyance level of each customer :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also keep a `Map<Key, Card>` to keep track of cards by their unique ID (`Key` might be `String`, `Integer`, etc). Then you could call [`remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29), which `Stack` inherits from `Vector`, passing in the `Card` you wanted removed.

This is assuming you're constrained to the `Stack` data structure, which you may not be (see other answers).

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to the "stack of cards" as a stack, but that should not be confused with a stack data structure.  I'll recommend two data structures for your card objects in your game:

1. A List to keep some form of ordering (so that you know in which order the cards are).  An ArrayList will work well here.
2. A HashHap for quick retrieval (remember, a Map usually loses its ordering).

As the SAME card will be present in both data structures, you won't be using that much more memory, but will have the advantages of both data structures (quick lookup and ordering).  You'll have to handle a bit of housekeeping, but that will be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's how a stack works. To get some other than the top item from a stack, you have to pop all items and push them on another stack until you found your item. Then you have to pop all the items from the other stack and push them back to the original stack.

That's what you'd do if you were looking for a card manually, too.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is LIFO and you have to pop items until you find needed one.Then push popped items back.You should use something like map to get an item with ID easier.